# In sql, How to get the highest unique primary key record, out of multiple foreign key of same ID records

Tags: sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

In my project I have a stored procedure.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[usp_SelectAllAspirantDetails]
as
begin

SELECT Distinct A.[AID]
      ,A.[Name]
      ,A.[Gender]
      ,A.[ContactNo]
      ,A.[EmailID]
      ,A.[SkillSet]
      ,A.[Experience]
      ,A.[CompanyName] 
      ,Aq.[Qualification]
      ,Aq.[InstituteName]
      ,Aq.[YearOfPass]
      ,Aq.[Percentage]  
      ,MAX(Aq.ID)
FROM [Aspirant] A FULL join AspirantQualification Aq ON A.AID=Aq.AID  
GROUP BY A.AID,A.[Name],A.[Gender],A.[ContactNo],A.[EmailID],A.[SkillSet],A.          
        [Experience],A.[CompanyName] ,Aq.[Qualification],Aq.[InstituteName] ,
        Aq.[YearOfPass],Aq.[Percentage]  
ORDER BY A.AID DESC
```

In this Aspirant AID is primary key and AspirantQualification is foreign key. I want to get the last entered record from AspirantQualification, if I have entered 10th,inter, degree are the qualifications I entered. I want Degree Record of that AID to display in gridview.

Comment: how do you decide the last entered record for an AID? is it the YearOfPass as the entry with maximum year should be the last qualification done by an Aspirant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write as:

```
create  procedure [dbo].[usp_SelectAllAspirantDetails]
as
begin


;WITH CTE as
(
select AID,ID,Qualification,InstituteName,YearOfPass,Percentage,
       row_number () over (partition by AID order by ID desc) as rownum
from AspirantQualification
)
Select A.[AID]
      ,A.[Name]
      ,A.[Gender]
      ,A.[ContactNo]
      ,A.[EmailID]
      ,A.[SkillSet]
      ,A.[Experience]
      ,A.[CompanyName] 
      ,Aq.[Qualification]
      ,Aq.[InstituteName]
      ,Aq.[YearOfPass]
      ,Aq.[Percentage] 
      ,Aq.ID
FROM [Aspirant] A 
LEFT JOIN CTE Aq ON A.AID=Aq.AID and Aq.rownum = 1

end
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/SQOPE61681) here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Your Help... Its Working absolutely fine

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY Aq.ID DESC,A.AID DESC
will do the trick I guess
if you want only latest record then add top one at the start after select

Comment: Thanks for the reply I made changes to my stored procedure as  'SELECT A.[AID]
      ,A.[Name]
      ,A.[Gender]
      ,A.[ContactNo]
      ,A.[EmailID]
      ,A.[SkillSet]
      ,A.[Experience]
      ,A.[CompanyName] 
   
      FROM [Aspirant] A 
      [EmailID],A.[SkillSet],A.[Experience],A.[CompanyName] ,Aq.[Qualification],Aq.[InstituteName] ,Aq.[YearOfPass],Aq.[Percentage]
      SELECT TOP(1)* FROM AspirantQualification Aq INNER join Aspirant A ON A.AID=Aq.AID ORDER BY ID desc'                                Now If i want to bind this to grid view, How can i do that!!